# Osmnx save big graph as graphml

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am downloading a big street network (Berlin). When I try to save it to the disc my laptop just do nothing for hours.

Is that normal?

My Code:

```
ox.save_graphml(G,“some_place.graphml“)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that can be normal. Is your CPU load indicator of your system showing that something is happening?

You have the following options:

- try a smaller street network and see if it finishes faster - to check if it works basically
- if you are on Linux you could execute your script with `strace python myscript.py` - you would see the low level system calls and notice if something is happening :-)
- Or try a python debugger and debug into the function

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Smaller street networks finish quite fast tho. I‘ll try the second option. For now I just saved the big network as shapefiles as a workaround.

Comment: GraphML saving should be marginally faster than shapefile saving. Sounds abnormal.